# Interactive drawings in webapp

Tags: javascript

For a web app I am designing, looking for a graphics library (java script based or not) to display in the browser. The application requires to map a production layout, so may only need to draw shapes (rectangles, cubes etc) and interactively modify the size of them. Any suggestion would be helpful. I am aware of widget libraries (jquerUI etc), and some graphing packages (protovis), but hope for something more suitable.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the `<canvas>` element? You'll have to do some abstraction for interaction and such, but it'll let you draw whatever you want.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

Comment: thanks looking though it.. meanwhile i found http://raphaeljs.com too..anxious to hear more options from SO experts.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

there are free apps that can do this for you.  Here is one on the chrome store

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pcflmbddgcmomcfngehfhlajjapabojh

EDIT -- I have nothing to do with that app, but it seems particularly suited to what you are asking for...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. it looks good, but it is a closed source program and has usage restrictions on free version. Canvas (though not widely supported yet) seems to be a good option so far as I have the freedom to draw basic graphics elements.. reading more.. thanks